# sets intersection and union discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

i have the following exercise:

$A =  \{a^{2n}*b^{m} : \space \space m,n  ∈\mathbb N, \space \space a, b > 0, \space \space a \neq
b \}$

$B =  \{a^{n}*b^{2m} : \space \space m,n  ∈\mathbb N, \space \space a, b > 0, \space \space a \neq b\}$

and now i have to decide what is right and what is wrong:

- $A \cup B =  \{a^{n}*b^{m} : m,n  ∈\mathbb N, \space \space 2|n \space \space and \space \space 2|m\}$
- $A \cup B =  \{a^{n}*b^{m} : m,n  ∈\mathbb N, \space \space 2|n \space \space or \space \space 2|m\}$
- $A \cap B =  \{a^{n}*b^{m} : m,n  ∈\mathbb N\}$
- $A \cap B =  \{a^{2n}*b^{2m} : m,n  ∈\mathbb N\}$

I have no any idea how to start with this exercise and hope you can give me some direction..thanks

Comment: Have you tried to search for counterexamples?  That might give you an idea of which statements are valid.

Comment: Some general advice: start with small examples.  E.g. list the elements of $A, B$ for $m, n \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ then check each of the four conjectures.

Comment: antkam, if some conjecture is right for the example set 1,2,3,4 i need also to prove that is working for all natural numbers not?

Comment: @omEchan - of course!  If a conjecture does not hold for the small example, then it is false.  If it holds for the small example, then the small example may give you ideas how to prove it, that's all.